# How to minimize cost of updating a sequence of nodes gathering data?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I have a sequence of k nodes `N1`, `N2`, `N3`, ... `Nk` each of which gets hit in succession (with possible skipping).

Every time I visit one of these nodes I need to += the time it took to get there from the previous node.  The tricky part is that if I come back to `N1` *without* reaching `Nk`, then these += updates should be dropped.

One method is to keep in each node two quantities: x and y. As we hop nodes we += values into y. If we get to `N1` we reset y to 0.  whereas if we reach `Nk` we do `x += y` for each node.

The problem is that every time we hit `Nk` it requires an O(n) operation--even if it might not be the common case for a sequence to return to `N1` without hitting `Nk`.  Is there a smarter way to do this more efficiently without an O(n) "commit" on every iteration reaching the end?

Consider this example with 3 nodes: `N_1`, `N_2`, `N_3`:

The left shows the subsequence of nodes hit on an iteration and the right shows what
the accumulation counters should contain:

```
(N_1, 2)(N_2, 3)(N_3, 7) ---> (N_1, 2)(N_2, 3)(N_3, 7)
(N_1, 4)(N_3, 2)         ---> (N_1, 6)(N_2, 3)(N_3, 9)
(N_1, 6)(N_2, 3)         ---> (N_1, 4)(N_2, 3)(N_3, 2) //nothing changes as this was an "invalid" op because we never hit the end node
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain two accumulators (`accum_[2]`) in each node, and a global 1-bit counter (`k_counter`) that is incremented when the k-th node is reached. Then maintain the invariant that `accum_[k_counter]` always has the right accumulation value for each node. In this scheme, if you skip nodes, you are forced to visit them, and perform `node[i] += 0` on them. That requirement could be optimized away with a visit counter, which I'll leave as an exercise :-).

```
enum { K = 100 };
struct Node *node;
struct Node {
    static bool k_counter;
    unsigned accum_[2];
    unsigned id_;
    Node () : accum_(), id_(this - node + 1) {}
    void operator += (unsigned time_data) {
        accum_[!k_counter] = accum_[k_counter] + time_data;
        if (id_ == K) k_counter = !k_counter;
    }
    operator unsigned () const { return accum_[k_counter]; }
};
bool Node::k_counter;

node = new Node[K];
```

Comment: I don't think this does what I was referring to though. I have edited my question with an example pass, but it is only the increments which occur on a subsequence that does not include the end node which must be ignored while all other ones accounted for..the above will switch accumulators every time it reaches the last node though.

Comment: @PalaceChan: Your example displays a strange requirement. Why does N_1 transition from 6 to 4, but N_2 stays at 3? In any case, I think the idea of a global flag to choose your counter behavior can be adapted for your specific problem. I can reduce my answer to just that hint, if you would rather.